# Simple Xtext example generates grammar that Antlr4 doesn't like - who's to blame?

Tags: antlr4, xtext

While using XText, I have come across a problem and I am not sure if Antlr4 or XText is at fault or if I'm just missing something.  I understand that Antlr4 is not supported by Xtext, but it seems like this particular case should not cause a problem.

Here is a simple Xtext file:

```
grammar com.github.jsculley.antlr4.Test with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate test "http://www.github.com/jsculley/antlr4/test"
aRule:
    name=STRING
;
```

STRING is defined in the XText rule from org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals:

```
terminal STRING : 
            '"' ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|'"') )* '"' |
            "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"
        ;
```

The generated Antlr grammar has the following rule:

```
RULE_STRING : ('"' ('\\' .|~(('\\'|'"')))* '"'|'\'' ('\\' .|~(('\\'|'\'')))* '\'');
```

The Antlr 3.5.2 tool has no problem with this rule, but the Antlr4 tool spits out the following errors:

```
error(50): InternalTest.g:102:29: syntax error: '(' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): InternalTest.g:102:62: syntax error: '(' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): InternalTest.g:102:74: syntax error: mismatched input ')' expecting SEMI while matching a lexer rule
error(50): InternalTest.g:106:25: syntax error: '(' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for lexer rule element
error(50): InternalTest.g:106:36: syntax error: mismatched input ')' expecting SEMI while matching a lexer rule
```

Antlr4 doesn't like the extra (and seemingly uneccessary) sets of parentheses around the group after each '~' operator.  So the question is, is Xtext generating a bad grammar, or is Antlr4 not handling a valid construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ANTLR 4 does not handle parenthesis correctly: [Parser issues mutual left recursion error when the left-recursive part of a rule is in parenthesis](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/564).

So, just remove useless parenthesis and ANTLR 4 should generate a fully ANLTR 3 compatible parser. I ported [PL/SQL](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql) grammar from ANTLR 3 -> ANTLR 4. Moreover, ANLTR 4 have a more powerfull parsing algorithm compare to the previous version.

Answer (score 2):

Xtext generates an Antlr 3.x grammar and Antlr 4 grammars are incompatible.

Comment: The grammars are not so different. Only tree rewriting is not allowed anymore and a few options (like `greedy` or `k`) can no longer be used (as they make no sense with the ALL(*) algorithm).